# Node html-pdf throws error inside node but works in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I am trying to create an a PDF file using the node package [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf)

I can make it work in my command line (on ubuntu) however in my program it throws the following error:

```
 events.js:72
            throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
                  ^
    Error: write EPIPE
        at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
        at Object.afterWrite (net.js:718:19)
```

Here is my code:

```
var html = '<b> Hello world </b>';
pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream){
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./foo.pdf'));
});
```

**UPDATE**

I have also tried with this code:

```
var options = {
    phantomPath: __dirname + "/../node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs",
    timeout: 30000,
    height: "1720px"
};

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./foo.pdf', callback);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.12.4",
    "ejs": "~2.3.1",
    "express": "~4.12.2",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "handbrake-js": "~2.0.5",
    "html-pdf": "^1.2.1",
    "html5-media-converter": "0.0.2",
    "jwt-simple": "~0.3.0",
    "multer": "~0.1.8",
    "phantom": "^0.7.2",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.17",
    "socket.io-stream": "~0.8.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.8.0"
  }
}
```

Please do note:

I have installed `phantomjs`
i have globally and locally installed the node module `html-pdf` and i have attempted other functions than `toStream` such as `toFile`.

None of them seem to work.

Please help!

Comment: Which `OS` are you using?, since it's working in `ubuntu`

Comment: @aba both of them are ubuntu 16.04

Comment: are you using latest node version? I am using `v0.10.25`

Comment: just to be sure you required both 'fs' (stored in fs) and 'html-pdf' (stored in pdf) in your code?

Comment: I just added this little bit code...

`var fs=require('fs');

var pdf = require('html-pdf');

var html = '<b> Hello world </b>';
pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream){
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./foo.pdf'));
});`

Comment: @Duly yes they are both required

Comment: can we see your package.json?

Comment: I have updated my question with my package.json

Comment: the only difference between my code and the first version yours is that I am using the latest version of html-pdf which is 2.1.0, and I did not even need to get phantom locally or globally (explicitly-a prebuilt version get downloaded when installing html-pdf ) to get it to work.

Comment: looks like they have had some issues with ubuntu, check out this link on github: https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/153